# Ionic issue: cant build android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

in a simple example of building an ionic app for android when i executed the command:

- ionic build android

the terminal display this (im on ubuntu 16.04): **Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.**

searching for the answer in internet i already define de ANDROID_HOME path and that things, here is my bashrc file:

```
ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"

ANDROID_HOME="/home/cristopher_ramirez/Android/Sdk"
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

even i modify the profile file and set the path there but that doesn't work too.

i already download the android targets from 18 to 25 (nougat) but that doesn't work either

anyone have any suggestions? i tried a lot of stuff but nothing works for me.

EDIT: i solve the problem:

1. first i have to install the latest version of gradle, then i set the
   path of gradle in the bashrc file (after doing that refresh it with
   **source ~/.bashrc**)
2. then you have to give root permission to cordova with this command **sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/USERNAME/.cordova**
3. finally i reconfigured the cordova configuration for android and that just worked for me.

Gradle and cordova are the ones you have to focus to solve this problem.

Comment: I had a similar error. Try this, Open a console and run "export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk"

Comment: @ELM donde that, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the path untill the sdk tool itself,

My android_home is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
for exemple
Even if your logic is the same idea